# show alert when second input box filled data from first box

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this code with me:

```
<input id="qfront" name="qfront" placeholder="Ketik Nama Kampus ..."
value="" type="text" onKeyPress="strQuery(this.value)"/> *<!--first inputbox-->*
<script>
function strQuery(str) {
     if (str.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById("valdata").value = "";
         return;
     } else {
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("valdata").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("POST", "inc.php?q="+str, true);
         xmlhttp.send(null);
     }
}
</script>
<input id="valdata" name="valdata" value="" type="text" onChange="showalert()"/>*<!--2nd inputbox-->*
<script>
function showalert(){
    var X =document.querySelector("#valdata").value;
    alert(X);
}
</script>
```

When I run `function strQuery(str)` it works 100% and show the result in the second inputbox (`#valdata`). When second inputbox contains data (from 1st inputbox). the second box not show alert

Do I miss something? How can I do this? (pls not using jquery). many thanks

Comment: Please clarify - The problem is that when the second has the data/string, alert not show.

Comment: Pls. I have edited my question

Comment: Do you mean that if 2nd inputbox has a value `xyz` and then when you run `strQuery` function, then alert does not show up?

Comment: yes. that's it. xyz comes from 1st inputbox

Comment: That is because nothing changed. Your 2nd inputbox has the same value.

Comment: perhaps. but pls spare your little time to check here: http://www.sman1bk.sch.id/lab/id/index.php
keyword must be: "universitas lampung"

Comment: What needs to be checked?

Comment: to check if var X show the #valdata value which comes from 1st inputbox. from stackoverflow I found many about onChange events I guess that's the problem, but I can't handle it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100708/discussion-between-jean-gkol-and-nikhil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution for my problem.
I fix the place of the second JS (showalert) into the first, as follows:

```
    <input id="qfront" name="qfront" placeholder="Ketik Nama Kampus ..."
 value="" type="text" onKeyPress="strQuery(this.value)"/>
            <script>
            function strQuery(str) {
                 if (str.length == 0) {
                     document.getElementById("valdata").value = "";
                     return;
                 } else {
                     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("valdata").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            showalert()
                         }
                     }
                     xmlhttp.open("POST", "inc.php?q="+str, true);
                     xmlhttp.send(null);
                 }
            }
            function showalert(){
                var X =document.querySelector("#valdata").value;
                alert(X);
            }
            </script>
            <input id="valdata" name="valdata" value="" type="text"/>
```

Thanks so much for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a missing double quote after `showalert();`

But separately, I think that onchange may only fire in response to user input.  If that's the case, simply change your code to:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("valdata").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("valdata").onchange();
}
```

Comment: no. it's not double events. ok, let me edit my question

Comment: @HermanNz that's odd - oh well my mistake - I'll delete my prior comment